# Doctrine 2 native PHP 8.1 enum support - using enum with query builder doesn't work

Tags: php, doctrine, php-8.1

Doctrine added [native support](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2022/01/11/orm-2.11.html) for PHP8.1 enumeration types.
It looks like it works on entity side as expected (saving entity on DB and hydration while fetching entity works as intended).
But while I try to fetch entity using repository query builder with where clause on enum field it throws an exception due to casting problems.

For example

```
$em->getRepository(SomeEntity::class)
   ->createQueryBuilder('s')
   ->where('s.enumStatus = :status')
   ->setParameter('status', EnumStatus::Pending)
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

will result in

```
Object of class EnumStatus could not be converted to string
in vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Statement.php (line 50)
```

Of course i can omit problem by doing `->setParameter('status', EnumStatus::Pending->value)` but this is kind of weird.

Em i doing something wrong or it just meant to be like this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available yet in official release.
There is merged PR that will add this in ORM `v.1.12.1`.

https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/9453/commits/9ebd07a36645236f01624754f7c71e0ff84c30b1#

https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/9372